# how to add namespace in soap web service response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

Here is my soap web service resposne

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns3:getShopInfoResponse xmlns:customns="http://test/" xmlns:ns3="http://service.prasad.com/">
            <return>
                <code>12345</code>
            </return>
        </ns3:getShopInfoResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope
```

In the above response beside code i want to have the namespace like this

```
<ns4:code xlmns:ns4="http://code.prasad.com">12345</code> like
```

,how can i get this

Below is the code which m using

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.prasad.service;

```
import com.prasad.code.Code;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

/**
 *
 * @author dell
 */

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class ShopInfo {

    @WebMethod
    public Code getShopInfo(String name){

       Code code = new Code();
       code.setCode("12345");

        if ("shop".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            code.setCode("Test Mart");
        }

        if ( "since".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            code.setCode("2012");
        }

        return code;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try annotate Code class with jaxb annotation. Example add `@XmlElement(namespace="http://code.prasad.com">12345")` to field code.

Comment: I tried the above one as well but the problem was that it is not coming exactly beside the                                                                                                                   
        <ns2:helloResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webserices.prasad.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.sample.com">
            <return>
                <ns3:code>12345</ns3:code>
            </return>

Comment: I think `<ns3:code>12345</ns3:code>` is correct namespace prefix. You do not need create new namespace prefix (ex. ns4) for the same namespace. I think this operation is not necessary becouse robot who read your response read correct namespace with prefix ns3